# Is it okay to use module.exports above functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

Is it acceptable to have the `module.exports` at the top of the file?  I'm trying to stick to the "above the fold" concept so all functions appear line-of-sight when opening a NodeJS file.

Example:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    doSomething      : doSomething,
    doSomethingElse  : doSomethingElse
};

var _      = require('lodash'),
    moment = require('moment');

function doSomething (value) {
    console.log('doSomething called with ' + value);
}

function doSomethingElse () {
    console.log('doSomethingElse called');
}
```

... or maybe ...

```
'use strict';

var service = {
    CONSTANT_VAR     : 'blah',
    doSomething      : doSomething,
    doSomethingElse  : doSomethingElse
};

var _      = require('lodash'),
    moment = require('moment');

function doSomething (value) {
    console.log('doSomething called with ' + value);
}

function doSomethingElse () {
    console.log('doSomethingElse called');
}

module.exports = service;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "acceptable" (edit: "okay")? Whether it is valid JavaScript? Whether it is good practice?

Comment: More of "good practice".  Would a guru freak out when they join our team?

Comment: Depends on the opinions of the guru.

Comment: There are arguments for both styles. And ES6 will change everything anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. [Functions are hoisted to the top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) so they'll be available when you need them. If you like that style, then go for it.

Example of hoisting:

```js
writeMessage('Hey!');

function writeMessage(msg) {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerText = msg;
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I know it'll technically work.  I'm just curious if it would upset any Node / Javascript Gods when the time comes I hand my project off.  Thoughts?

Comment: @G.Deward Some people get fussy about it, others swear by it. My opinion is do what makes the most sense for the situation. If that makes sense for you, go for it.